# Exe4J return Exception "?

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, exe4j

I am using exe4j and I'm trying generate an exe file, after generated I try execute but does not work.

here the problem

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant
    at iguana.Principal.<init>(Principal.java:69)
    at iguana.Principal$32.run(Principal.java:1187)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.ReadableInstant
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are missing a joda-time class. My only thought might be that you are missing the library for it, which can be downloaded here:
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/
Or, if you use maven like me, add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to your POM file.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you left a library out of your executable.  It can't find the org.joda.time package.

There are 2 probable solutions:

1. If the library got left out, add it.
2. If the library is already included, check that the classpath shows where it is.

[Here](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/exe4j/help/doc/) is the exe4j help page that shows how to edit the classpath.

Comment: I dont know why this happens, because when I run "clean and build" in NetBeans it create my jar file and execute normally but when I am creating the exe file with exe4j does not work. 
I have JodaTime library in folder lib of my project, so I not understand why the problem, you know ??
I am not using maven.

Comment: Wow....the problem was with the classpath, I added library jodatime and h2 database now work. But how to do to add all my libs into lib directory ??? There is a way ? I see this: http://resources.ej-technologies.com/exe4j/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/exe4j/help/doc/wizard/java.html  But I dont understand. thanks.